# Spring bean is not being created in Websphere 8.0

Tags: java, spring, maven, websphere, spring-jms

I am testing a legacy application(**alpha.ear**). containing two artifacts 
   **alphafirst.jar** and **alphasecond.jar** .

**aplhafirst.jar** is using **spring.jar** and **alphasecond.jar** is using **spring version 3.0.3** because I needed JMS functionality in spring.

Now when I deploy the ear file it throws the following exception :
 >

```
alpha.ear/alphasecond.jar!/alphasecond-context-jms.xml]: Bean class [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] not found; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'managed' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/testServer/.weld/profiles/64bit/base/testServer/installedApps/node01/alpha.ear/alphafirst.jar!/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Error registering bean with name 'jmsContainer' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/testServer/.weld/profiles/64bit/base/testServer/installedApps/node01/alpha.ear/alphasecond.ear!/alphasecond-context-jms.xml]: Bean class [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] not found; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Error registering bean with name 'jmsContainer' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/testServer/.weld/profiles/64bit/base/testServer/installedApps/node01/alpha.ear/alphasecond.ear!/alphasecond-context-jms.xml]: Bean class [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] not found; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Error registering bean with name 'jmsContainer' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/testServer/.weld/profiles/64bit/base/testServer/installedApps/node01/alpha.ear/alphasecond.ear!/alphasecond-context-jms.xml]: Bean class [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] not found; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer
        at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:160)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:910)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:138)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:652)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:314)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:82)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:156)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:257)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:168)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:332)
        at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:136)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:380)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:271)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:152)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet.init(ContextLoaderServlet.java:81)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:341)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1375)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:655)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:621)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:449)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:901)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1219)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1514)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:704)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1096)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:786)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1421)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2232)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5488)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5614)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1311)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:620)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:608)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:477)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1386)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:195)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:477)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:970)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:517)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:338)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:961)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:294)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1820)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Here is my xml files :

**alphasecond-context-jms.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>


    <bean id="JmsDcsvcCF" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="queueConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="username" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="queueConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
          <property name="queueManager" value="mqMgr1" />
          <property name="hostName" value ="xxxx-yyy-dev.yyy.xxx.com" />
          <property name="channel" value ="xxxx.yyyy.zzzz" />
          <property name="port" value ="1111" />
          <property name="transportType" value ="1"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dealingJobReq" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="ssss.ssss" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTaskMessageListener" class="test.JmsTaskMessageListener"/>

    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="JmsDcsvcCF"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="dealingJobReq"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="jmsTaskMessageListener" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

**JmsTaskMessageListener.java**

```
public class JmsTaskMessageListener implements MessageListener {

   private static final String INVALID_MESSAGE_TYPE_PASSED = "Invalid message type passed to fromMessage ";
    private static final Log log = LogFactory
            .getLog(JmsTaskMessageListener.class);


    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        System.out.println(" ~~~~  ~~~ onMessage - Start~~~~~~~~");

        MQRequestMessage requestEvent = null;
        Date initiatedTime = null;


        } catch (JMSException e) {
        }  catch (Exception e) {

        }

        log.info("###### onMessage - End here ########");
    }
}
```

**beanRefContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">


<beans>

    <bean id="managed" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:alphasecond-context-jms.xml</value> 
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

beanRefContext.xml is in `alphafirst.jar` and loaded by spring `ContextLoaderListener`.

Any hints/solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. Have you made sure this class is on the classpath?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian : Class is in classpath

Comment: Where in the classpath?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian : spring-jms-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar is there at classpath of alphasecond.jar .

Comment: Bottom line: it's not finding that class. So there's a classloader issue/conflict between the different jars and their dependencies. Maybe you can get some ideas from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/crun_classload.html or https://websphereapplicationservernotes.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/classnotfound-a-close-look-at-class-loader-in-websphere-application-server/